# Combobox Datasource assign to Datatable

Tags: vb.net, combobox, casting, datatable

How to convert Datasource of a Combobox  to Datatable in VB.net?
I know how to `assign datatable to combobox`. In this case I need to do it opposite way.

Like:

> `dim dt as  DataTable = combobox1.DataSource`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `TryCast` to get the job done.

```
Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(combobox1.DataSource, DataTable)

If dt Is Nothing Then
    ' It didn't work because it's not a datatable
    ' Editors: I specifically did not reduce this expression
    '          to emphasize the need to check for 'Nothing'
    '          and handle it appropriately.
Else
    ' Yay it's a datatable
End If
```